# About relativity and train

Tags: special-relativity

Imagine a train moving with velocity v wrt a reference frame S, there is a clock in the rear and in the front of the train, and them are synchronized in the train reference, let's call this reference frame S'.
If you, the reference frame S, take a look simultaneously wrt your reference on the clocks, how will the time be relationed?
OBS: This is not a question, it is a doubt about the theory.
This is a well know fact in special relativity, the rear will be beyond the front by $Lv/c^{2}$, but i am not sure why!!
See:
To both clocks being synchronized in the train reference, i will imagine a clock on the middle of the train of length proper L. When the light get in each side, the clock of its side starts to "click".

But, in the ground frame, the photon will need $$L/2(c-v)$$ to get in the rear, and $$L/2(c+v)$$ to came in the front. That is $$\delta t = Lv/(c^2-v^2)$$ and not Lv/c²!

Where is the error in this assumption?

Comment: speed of photon is c in every frame.

Comment: I am not saying it is not
$$L + vt = ct$$
$$t = L/(c-v)$$

this is what i am doing

Comment: You have a "you frame", a "ground frame", and an $S$ frame. Are they all the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are comparing things in different coordinates, which always causes problems in relativity, and you do it twice:

(1) The train is not $L$ in $S$, it is $L/\gamma$, which brings your formula to:

$$ \delta t = \frac L {\gamma}\frac v {c^2-v^2} $$

Note that:

$$ \frac 1 {c^2-v^2} = \frac 1 {c^2} \gamma^2 $$

so that :

$$ \delta t = \frac L {\gamma}\frac v {c^2}\gamma^2 = \gamma\delta t' $$

(2)The offset between the front and back clocks, $\delta t'$, observed in $S$ is not a time measured in $S$, it is a coordinate difference observed in $S'$. You can related it to a time in $S$ per the prescription in the OP:

$$ \delta t = \gamma \delta t'$$.